# Unable to render image uploaded within Electron app, built with electron-forge

Tags: electron

I have a file uploader for users to store images, which I'm saving content to a folder within the application data directory (app.getPath('userData')). This all works fine.
When I attempt to load the image using a basic image tag, with the src pointing to the correct location within the application data directory, it fails to render. 
This only occurs after I've packaged the app using electron-forge (make & package). I've only attempted to make for OS-X (darwin x-64). I'm guessing it has something to do with asar, but I can't seem to get this working. I've attempted to use the file protocol for the image source too.
Any idea how to correctly do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way is to serve all content up from a server bound to localhost